# Where are the separate .dtx files of the source2e.tex

Tags: dtx

I'm analyzing the source2e.tex file in an effort to better understand (La)TeX, and I see a load of separate `.dtx` files:

```
\DocInclude{ltdirchk} % System dependent initialisation
\DocInclude{ltplain}  % LaTeX version of Knuth's plain.tex
\DocInclude{ltvers}   % Current version date
\DocInclude{ltdefns}  % Initial definitions.
\DocInclude{ltalloc}  % Allocation of counters and others.
\DocInclude{ltcntrl}  % Program control macros.
\DocInclude{lterror}  % Error handling.
\DocInclude{ltpar}    % Paragraphs.
\DocInclude{ltspace}  % Spacing, line and page breaking.
\DocInclude{ltlogos}  % Logos.
\DocInclude{ltfiles}  % \input files and related commands
\DocInclude{ltoutenc} % Output encoding interface
\DocInclude{ltcounts} % Counters
\DocInclude{ltlength} % Lengths
\DocInclude{ltfssbas} % NFSS Base macros
\DocInclude{ltfsstrc} % NFSS Tracing (and tracefnt.sty)
\DocInclude{ltfsscmp} % NFSS1 Compatibility
\DocInclude{ltfssdcl} % NFSS Declarative interface
\DocInclude{ltfssini} % NFSS Initialisation
\DocInclude{fontdef}  % fonttext.ltx/fontmath.ltx
\DocInclude{preload}  % preload.ltx
\DocInclude{ltfntcmd} % \textrm etc
\DocInclude{ltpageno} % Page numbering
\DocInclude{ltxref}   % Cross referencing
\DocInclude{ltmiscen} % Miscellaneous environment definitions.
\DocInclude{ltmath}   % Mathematics set up.
\DocInclude{ltlists}  % List and related environments
\DocInclude{ltboxes}  % Parbox and friends
\DocInclude{lttab}    % Tabbing tabular and array
\DocInclude{ltpictur} % Picture mode
\DocInclude{ltthm}    % Theorem environments
\DocInclude{ltsect}   % Sectioning
\DocInclude{ltfloat}  % Floats
\DocInclude{ltidxglo} % Index and Glossary
\DocInclude{ltbibl}   % Bibliography
\DocInclude{ltpage}   % \pagestyle \raggedbottom \sloppy
\DocInclude{ltoutput} % Output routine
\DocInclude{ltclass}  % Package & Class interface
\DocInclude{lthyphen} % Hyphenation (hyphen.ltx).
\DocInclude{ltluatex} % Luatex support
\DocInclude{ltfinal}  % Last minute initialisations and dump
```

Where can I find them in my system? I already checked the MiKTeX 2.9 folder where I found most files I wanted so far (for instance, article.cls, geometry.sty).

Comment: All are combined in `latex.ltx`, for example, if you prefer one single file

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I usually use latex.ltx but that is rather different, all the documentation is stripped out, it isn't "just" the dtx source files combined.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i found the `source2e.tex` in `MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base` - however there isn't a single `.dtx` file in there!?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, I know that the documentation is stripped.

Comment: @Zac I deleted that comment it seems it does get packaged in tex/latex/base (seems wrong but whatever:-) You might have thought I knew where the file was, since I wrote it, but....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's probably my fault: I'll adjust our build script to sort it!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i found a file named `ltxbase-src.tar` inside `MiKTeX 2.9\source`. all the `.dtx` files appear to be in there :]

Comment: they are also on ctan of course in latex/base

Answer (score 3):

The LaTeX2e kernel sources live inside `sources/latex/base`: you should be able to find them by doing for example

```
kpsewhich ltvers.dtx
```

at the Command Line (for me it gives `c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/source/latex/base/ltvers.dtx`).

There are multiple source files since the LaTeX kernel is *big* (current release is 8820 lines). There needs to be some logical structure to the sources, so they are split up into different areas. One sees the same in for example `expl3` or TikZ, and I'm also working on a similar split for `siunitx` for similar reasons.